# I can't find the declaration of a Gradle task

Tags: gradle

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
println 'First top level script element'

task first {
    println 'First task: Configuration'

    doLast {
        println 'First task: Action'
    }
}

task second(dependsOn: first) {
    println 'Second task: Configuration'

    doLast {
        println 'Second task: Action'
    }
}

println 'Second top level script element'
```

Following my tutorial, I got the following exercises:

> 1. Execute the `help` task and observe the output.
> 2. Execute the `first` task and observe the output.
> 3. Execute the `second` task and observe the output.

Now, I executed:

```
$ gradle help
```

And it works. But how can it be if the task `help` is not declared anywhere?
Am I looking at the correct file at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle provides a set of tasks out of the box, including a `help` task. You may use `gradle tasks --all` to get a list of all tasks available to your project. This will be particularly useful once you apply plugins to your build script, because those plugins may create tasks implicitly. For a lot of use cases, is it not even necessary at all to manually create tasks. As an example, the following minimal build script provides all you need to build Java projects:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
```

You may even run `gradle tasks` in an empty folder (without an `build.gradle` file) and Gradle will still offer you its default tasks, as it will automatically create a project based on an empty `build.gradle` file.